# Error when running query as a subquery

Tags: sql-server, ssms, subquery

The inner query runs successfully alone, but when I run it as a subquery, an error pop up.

My query:

```
Select  TOP 3 * 
FROM (select 
        fr.rating
        ,   sp.SpId
        ,sp.FName
        ,sp.LName
        ,sp.DpUrl
        ,sp.CoverUrl
        ,sp.city
        ,s.ServiceTitle 
    from ServiceProvider as sp 
        inner join SpServices as ss on sp.SpId=ss.SpId 
        inner join Services as s on ss.ServiceId=s.ServiceId 
        inner join FinalRating as fr on fr.spid=sp.SpId 
    where s.ServiceTitle='Laptop Repairing' ORDER BY fr.rating DESC)
```

Comment: Try putting the ending parenthesis after `'Laptop Repairing'` instead of after `desc`.

Comment: after putting parenthesis before order by clause following error pop up
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 60
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'."

Comment: You are creating a derived table - try putting an alias on your derived table. Ex:  `'Laptop Repairing') a`

Comment: You don't need a subquery to select the top 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, sql server really doesn't like your ORDER BY in the subquery.
And as tiolbe already in the cmment every derived table needs a alias

```
Select  TOP 3 * 
FROM (select 
        fr.rating
        ,   sp.SpId
        ,sp.FName
        ,sp.LName
        ,sp.DpUrl
        ,sp.CoverUrl
        ,sp.city
        ,s.ServiceTitle 
    from ServiceProvider as sp 
        inner join SpServices as ss on sp.SpId=ss.SpId 
        inner join Services as s on ss.ServiceId=s.ServiceId 
        inner join FinalRating as fr on fr.spid=sp.SpId 
    where s.ServiceTitle='Laptop Repairing' ) t1
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: giving this error now
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
The multi-part identifier "fr.rating" could not be bound.

Comment: ok the alias fr i sunknown, try the changed answer

Comment: I want the inner query result in desc order by fr.rating
then i want to select top 3 from that result

Comment: the order in a subqueries is not possible, and gives an error, because tables are by definition  unsorted, and it also doesn't matter where you put it

Comment: so if i put order by outside sub query then how can i use order by on fr.rating column

Comment: no remove the tr, as shown in the answer

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked.